# Jasper Reports : Same template for CSV and PDF Issue

Tags: java, jasper-reports

I have a report where the export result in pdf and csv differ in some columns and I want to use the same template for both exports. CSV would have more or less columns compared to PDF output. Im using **JRCsvMetadataExporter** as my CSV exporter. So what I tried to do is create a separate band for CSV and PDF, In the band intended for CSV, my code was like

```
<band height="0">
  <printWhenExpression><![CDATA[Boolean.FALSE]]></printWhenExpression>
  <textField>
      <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="119" height="0">
            <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.export.csv.column.name" value="Column_1"/>
             <propertyExpression name="net.sf.jasperreports.export.csv.data"><![CDATA[$F{COL_1}]]></propertyExpression>
       </reportElement>
   </textField>
</band>
```

But when I ran the export, nothing was getting generated for CSV, I was expecting when **printWhenExpression** is false, it wont be included in the PDF export and CSV exporter will include columns mentioned in the band. Could anyone let me know what Im doing wrong here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If printWhenExpression is hard coded with Boolean.FALSE then it will never appear in PDF and CSV. Try to add the element with width and height as 0 in the jrxml which will make it not appear in the PDF but it will appear in the CSV since you are using the JRCsvMetadataExporter